# How to parse Google Distance Matrix API JSON in IOS SWIFT 3 the correct way

Tags: ios, json, swift3, google-distancematrix-api

I have searched a lot to correctly parse a multi dimensional JSON arrays in swift. From the search results , what i could grasp was that it some what similar to retro-fit parsing in Android. i.e  creating a parsing class for each json response. Please excuse me if i am making a mistake. I am new to IOS swif.

This is the distance matrix api json output for my distance call

```
{
  "destination_addresses" : [ "My Destination" ],
  "origin_addresses" : [
     "My Source"
  ],
  "rows" : [
     {
        "elements" : [
           {
              "distance" : {
                 "text" : "23.3 km",
                 "value" : 23333  //lastly i take this 
              },
              "duration" : {
                 "text" : "49 mins",
                 "value" : 2938
              },
              "status" : "OK"    //then i check this
           }
        ]
     }
  ],
  "status" : "OK"    //first i check this
}
```

This how i did it

This is my api call(works fine)

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=latitude,longitude&destinations=latitude,longitude&mode=driving&language=en-EN&sensor=false

```
func extract_Validate(jsonData:NSData)
    {
        var distInMeters = 0
        var chkVarOne = "notOK"
        let json1 = NSString(data: jsonData as Data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        let data = json1!.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue, allowLossyConversion: false)
        print(data!)
        do{
            print("Inside do")
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData as Data, options:.allowFragments) as! NSObject
            if let dictionary = json as? [String: Any] {
                print("inside dictionary ")
                if let detailsDict = dictionary as? NSDictionary {
                    print("Parse Data")

                    for (key, value) in detailsDict {

                        print("Property: \"\(key as! String)\"")
                        if key as! String == "status" && value as! String == "OK"{
                        chkVarOne = "OK"
                        }
                        if chkVarOne == "OK"
                        {
                        if key as! String == "rows"
                        {
                            if let elementsDict = value as? NSDictionary {
                            for(keyEle, valueEle) in elementsDict{
                            }
                        }
                            if let elementsDict = value as? NSArray
                            {
                                if let array = elementsDict as? [Any] {
                                    if let firstObject = array.first {

                                        if let distanceSet  = firstObject as? NSDictionary{

                                            for(keyDis, valueDis) in distanceSet{

                                                  // print("Property: \"\(keyDis as! String)\"")
                                                if keyDis as! String == "elements"
                                                {
                                                    if let DistDict = valueDis as? NSDictionary {

                                                        for(keyDict, valueDict) in DistDict{

                                                               print("Property: \"\(keyDict as! String)\"")
                                                        }
                                                    }

                                                    if let DistDict = valueDis as? NSArray {

                                                       // print(DistDict)

                                                        if let distArr = DistDict as?[Any]{

                                                            if let frst = distArr.first{
                                                                //print(frst)
                                                                if let distOne = frst as? NSDictionary{
                                                                    var checkvar = "notOK"
                                                                    for(ketOneDis, valOneDis) in distOne{

                                                                       // print("Property: \"\(ketOneDis as! String)\"", valOneDis)

                                                                        if ketOneDis as! String == "status" && valOneDis as! String == "OK"{

                                                                          checkvar = "OK"

                                                                        }

                                                                        if checkvar == "OK"
                                                                        {
                                                                            if ketOneDis as! String == "distance"
                                                                            {
                                                                               // print(valOneDis)

                                                                                if let valtwoDis = valOneDis as? NSDictionary{
                                                                                    for(kDis, vDis) in valtwoDis{
                                                                                      //  print("Property: \"\(kDis as! String)\"", vDis)

                                                                                        if kDis as! String == "value"{

                                                                                            distInMeters = vDis as! Int
                                                                                    }
                                                                                }
                                                                                if let valTwoDis = valOneDis as? NSArray{
                                                                                    print(valTwoDis)
                                                                                }
                                                                            }
                                                                        }

                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                         //print(distanceSet,"rttgtgtgtgtgtgtg")
                                        }
                                        if let distSet = firstObject as? NSArray{
                                            print(distSet,"dfdffddfdfdfd")
                                        }
                                    }

                                }
                            }
                        }

                        //let rows
                    }
                  }
                } //ending here
            }
          }
        }
        catch{
            print("error in JSONSerialization")
        }

        print(distInMeters," is the resulting value")

    }
```

This code is working fine fine. But i know this is not the way to do it.

So please help me

I think there might be some errors occur in this code later. Don't know for sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest and most effective way to do this is by using object mapping. Something like Gloss (https://github.com/hkellaway/Gloss) would do the trick. In your case you will have the following classes (objects):

**Response**

```
  import Foundation 
import Gloss

//MARK: - Response
public struct Response: Glossy {

    public let destinationAddresses : [String]!
    public let originAddresses : [String]!
    public let rows : [Row]!
    public let status : String!



    //MARK: Decodable
    public init?(json: JSON){
        destinationAddresses = "destination_addresses" <~~ json
        originAddresses = "origin_addresses" <~~ json
        rows = "rows" <~~ json
        status = "status" <~~ json
    }


    //MARK: Encodable
    public func toJSON() -> JSON? {
        return jsonify([
        "destination_addresses" ~~> destinationAddresses,
        "origin_addresses" ~~> originAddresses,
        "rows" ~~> rows,
        "status" ~~> status,
        ])
    }

}
```

**Element:**

```
import Foundation 
import Gloss

//MARK: - Element
public struct Element: Glossy {

    public let distance : Distance!
    public let duration : Distance!
    public let status : String!



    //MARK: Decodable
    public init?(json: JSON){
        distance = "distance" <~~ json
        duration = "duration" <~~ json
        status = "status" <~~ json
    }


    //MARK: Encodable
    public func toJSON() -> JSON? {
        return jsonify([
        "distance" ~~> distance,
        "duration" ~~> duration,
        "status" ~~> status,
        ])
    }

}
```

**Row:**

```
import Foundation 
import Gloss

//MARK: - Row
public struct Row: Glossy {

    public let elements : [Element]!



    //MARK: Decodable
    public init?(json: JSON){
        elements = "elements" <~~ json
    }


    //MARK: Encodable
    public func toJSON() -> JSON? {
        return jsonify([
        "elements" ~~> elements,
        ])
    }

}
```

**Distance:**

```
import Foundation 
import Gloss

//MARK: - Distance
public struct Distance: Glossy {

    public let text : String!
    public let value : Int!



    //MARK: Decodable
    public init?(json: JSON){
        text = "text" <~~ json
        value = "value" <~~ json
    }


    //MARK: Encodable
    public func toJSON() -> JSON? {
        return jsonify([
        "text" ~~> text,
        "value" ~~> value,
        ])
    }

}
```

After creating the classes, you map the JSON to the Object by doing the following:

```
let jsonResponse = ..//Your JSON response
guard let distanceResponse = Response(json: jsonResponse) else { 
    // handle decoding failure here
}
//You can use the distanceResponse object here as an object and access it's values.
```

Learn more about object mapping in this tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/150322/swift-json-tutorial-2

Comment: my question is can we parse it without the help of any other libraries? I mean like in android?

Comment: Of course you can, but it is not as effective as using object mapping. You will end up with a lot of if/guard statements and for loops which will lead to errors (like the code you have). :-)

Comment: From Swift 4 is possible to parse json without the help of other libraries. There is Decodable https://medium.com/swiftly-swift/swift-4-decodable-beyond-the-basics-990cc48b7375